# Cannot install libgnuradio-osmosdr0.1.4

Tags: software-installation, gnuradio

So i have to install libgnuradio-osmosdr0.1.4 package for a project but it gets me this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install libgnuradio-osmosdr0.1.4


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgnuradio-osmosdr0.1.4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgnuradio-osmosdr0.1.4' has no installation candidate
```

I tried apt update, but it doesnt work.

I am on ubuntu 20.04 and amd64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgnuradio-osmosd&searchon=names) for Ubuntu for `libgnuradio-osmosd`: You need `libgnuradio-osmosdr0.2.0` for all Ubuntu other then 18.04/Bionic.

If you can not use 0.2.0 then that means your project needs an upgrade to support it. That is the safest method; you could add the "universe" repository for 18.04 to your system and install `libgnuradio-osmosdr0.1.4` from that and [pin it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) but that is a temporary band-aid.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Comment: @kaankaya cool :) I was still adding stuff *like how to pin the 18.04 version if you reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaallly wanted that